# Is there any way to fuzz a HTTP response field via Burp Intruder?

Tags: web-application, burp-suite

I found a privilege escalation bug in an HTTP response page and I want to fuzz one of the field with ID values that define the admin role and see if any other viable ID comes up. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you have experience with the Burp Intruder? Have you tried something already? Where do you get stuck? Do you mean request field?

Comment: I think he talks about "response" fields. I'm not sure there is a way to fuzz responses.

Comment: yep, responses. just wondering if anyone out there have a trick to fuzz response, i read abit about session handling with macro but no luck in fuzzing it.

Comment: What would altering the response buy you? I don't see a security issue other than a mitm?